# Updating a html table dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My web page contains a drop-down and a table. When the user makes a selection in the drop-down this will dynamically populate the table with data.
I am wondering what is the best way to populate this table.
I am using Spring MVC and JSPs for my server side technology. After the user makes the drop-down selection we will most likely make a separate request to retrieve the data, as opposed to retrieving it all at the outset.
One idea I have is as follows:

1. Use JSP to create a dummy table row which will be hidden
2. After response with data is retrieved, convert to JSON objects
3. Use JS/JQuery to clone the dummy row for each JSON object

Is this a good solution? Or may there be a better way?

Comment: That approach is perfectly fine, and probably efficient to some extend as you are only requesting data on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the data is extremely voluminous or rapidly changing "live" information, then serve it with the page in a series of `<tbody id="xxx">...</tbody>` elements - one per drop-down option - within the table. To the dropdown menu attach an 'onchange' handler, which shows the tbody corresponding to the currently selected option, and hides all others.

If necessary, you can adopt a similar approach with AJAX to fetch the data. Serve the page with empty `<tbody id="xxx">...</tbody>` elements - one per option. Then populate the tbodys  "on demand" from the dropdown's onchange handler and show/hide as above. If appropriate, you can include a test in the inchange handler to ensure that each data set is only fetched once - if data has already been received, then it will be cached in its tbody. Eventually, when all tbodys are populated, this solution becomes identical to the one above.

Answer (score 0):

A better way might be to use something like handlebars.js or mustache.js templates (or any other front-end templating engine) as they both take a JSON object and insert it into a template that can be appended to your html. This works very well if you are getting data via AJAX, even better if the AJAX return JSON anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If your project allows third party JQuery plugins I recommend looking at [DataTables](http://datatables.net/). Out of the box it should do everything you need. I've used DT on various projects for a few years now and find it to be a powerful and stable plugin.